# php - context node in xpath problem

Tags: php, xpath

have this code:

```
$products   =   $feed->_xpath->query( "//cf:vehicle"  );

foreach( $products as $product )
{
    echo $product->nodeName . ': ' . $product->getAttribute('code') . '<br />';
    $imgs   =   $feed->_xpath->query( "//cf:image" , $product );
    echo '&nbsp;Imgs: ' . $imgs->length . '<br />';
}
```

the number of product nodes found in the xmlfeed is 103 - that is correct.

the query to locat images within that node however is NOT doing so within the current node context - it finds 116 image nodes which is the total number of image nodes within the feed where as it should only select the images within the current product (between 0 and 3 in most cases)

Any pointers muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have to use `.//cf:image` to make it relative to the context node.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev:

> //para selects all the para descendants of the document root and thus selects all para elements in the same document as the context node

and

> .//para selects the para element descendants of the context node

Also see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34413

Comment: cheers Gordon - yet another massive oversight to add to my portfolio!

Comment: A path starting with `/` or `//` operator is an absolute path. For a relative path use `.` (`self::node()` abbreviation) or just `descendant::cf:image`.