# How to search by id under a given element?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

How can I search a `DOMElement` by `id`, that appears under another `DOMElement`?

```php
$element->ownerDocument->getElementById('my-id');
```

...will search the whole document. I only want the element to be returned if it appears under `$element`.

Comment: Is XPath an option for you?

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro It is!

Comment: @Benjamin FYI There is [**phpQuery**](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery), not sure if that user knew about it ...

Comment: @HamZa I heard about phpQuery, but this is not an option for me right now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simple with [XPath](http://php.net/domxpath):

```
$xpath = new DomXpath($element->ownerDocument);
$subelement = $xpath->query('descendant::*[@id="my-id"]', $element);
```

Basically, it looks for an element anywhere in the tree below the context node (`$element` here) with the `id` attribute equal to `my-id`...

Comment: Actually there was a syntax error in your XPath expression, and it returned elements outside `$element`. I've taken the liberty to update your answer with the code that works for me now!

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with XPath. The following will have the that element (the typical less than 120 chars one-liner):

```
$idElement = ($r = simplexml_import_dom($element)->xpath('.//*[@id="my-id"]')) 
             ? dom_import_simplexml($r[0]) : NULL;
```

If it's not found, you will get `NULL`. What this basically does is using the short-hand form what @ircmaxell suggested in his answer:

```
descendant::*[@id="my-id"]
.//*[@id="my-id"]
```

The context-node is the same, in simplexml xpath, it's automatically to the context-node, in DOMXPath you need to specify it.

> *oh just seeing, it's you who edited the xpath in that answer, so the important part is when bound to the context-node, to use the dot `.` before the double slashes `//` as the slash otherwise will go to the root again, the dot prevents this (compare with specifying a relative file-path in your file-system).*
>
> See as well: [php - context node in xpath problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4266091/367456)